# Need grep statement to exclude lines

Tags: bash, shell, grep

I am running ufw in "open" mode just to collect stats to see if there are any attempts to access the server. UFW is running in "medium" logging so I can see all access to the server. When I check ufw.log, I need to run through the whole list manually.

I currently use:

```
grep 'IN=eth0' uwf.log
```

But this still leaves too many records for me to check manually

What I really need is:

- Grep must only look for lines that contain IN=eth0 ( This part is
  easy)
- Grep must IGNORE lines with SRC=0.0.0.0 (These are dhcp broadcasts)
- Grep must IGNORE lines with SRC=10.0.1.15 (10.0.X.X is my Nagios checking ftp service)

Can someone please help,

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use `awk`:

```
awk '/IN=eth0/ && !/SRC=0\.0\.0\.0/ && !/SRC=10\.0\.1\.15/' uwf.log
```

Since `awk` supports boolean operations, multiple conditions can be expressed in a pretty simple way.

Answer (score 3):

`grep -v` : This will make grep to exclude lines which matches the pattern.
   `grep -E` : This will make grep to accept regular expressions (in this case multiple possibilities - which is separated by pipe).

```
grep "IN=eth0" uwf.log |grep -Ev 'SRC=0\.0\.0\.0|SRC=10\.0\.1\.15'
```

Comment: Perhaps writing about `-v` would make the answer better?

Comment: @Reut what about commenting about the pipe ?

Comment: @Flint the pipe is not at the core of the answer.

Comment: I don't think `-E` switch is needed.

Answer (score 0):

With GNU sed:

```
sed -rn '/IN=eth0/{/(SRC=0\.0\.0\.0|SRC=10\.0\.1\.15)/!p}' uwf.log
```